# Why does string + fixnum addition generate coercion error?

Tags: ruby

Why does ruby addition cannot coerce given string to fixnum and vice verca?

```
irb>fixnum = 1
=> 1
irb> fixnum.class
=> Fixnum
irb> string = "3"
=> "3"
irb> string.class
=> String
irb> string.to_i
=> 3
irb> fixnum + string
TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum
    from (irb):96:in `+'
    from (irb):96
    from :0
irb(main):097:0>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because ruby doesn't know whether you want to convert the string to int or the int to string. In e.g. java `1 + "3"` is `"13"`. Ruby prefers to raise an error, so that the user can decide whether to `to_s` the one operand or `to_i` the other, rather than doing the wrong thing automatically.

Comment: That's why I expect automatic coercion from ruby. BTW python says the same:  "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"

Answer (score 5):

It spits out an error because ruby doesn't know what you want. String + fixnum is an ambiguous statement. It could either mean that you want to add the int value of the string and the number, or the string value of the int and the string. For example:

```
str = "5"
num =  3

puts str.to_i + num
=> 8

puts str + num.to_s
=> 53
```

Rather than taking a guess as to which of those you want, ruby just throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the variable back to itself, since doing a `.to_i` returns a integer value, but doesn't modify the original object.

```
>> string = "3"
=> "3"
>> string.class
=> String
>> string.to_i
=> 3
>> string
=> "3"
>> string.class
=> String
>> string = string.to_i
=> 3
>> string.class
=> Fixnum
```

Answer (score 1):

`Fixnum#+` is just a method. Simplified it works like this:

```
class Fixnum
  def +(other)
    if Fixnum === other
      # normal operation
    else
      n1, n2= other.coerce(self)
      return n1+n2
    end
  end
end
```

`coerce` is used for automatic numerical type conversion. This is used for example if you do `42 + 3.141`. A string in ruby cannot automaticly be converted into numerical values. You could enhance the `String` class to be able to do this. You just need to do

```
class String
  def coerce(other)
    coerced= case other
    when Integer
      self.to_i
    when
      self.to_f
    end
    return coerced, other
  end
end
```

Now you can do

```
23 + "42" # => 65
0.859 - "4" # => 3.141
```

This does not work the other way arround. `coerce` is only for numerical values `"23" + 42` won't work. `String#+` will not use coerce.

The simplified `+` is done in `Fixnum` and not in `Integer` on purpose. `Fixnum` and `Bignum` have their separate methods, because they work internally very different.